# Navigation bar right bar button item is not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

```
- (void)setRightNavigationBarViewForUser {
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                               target:nil action:nil];
    spacer.width = 760;
    NSString *title = [VimondStore sessionManager].userName;

    UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 144, 44)];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 0, 44, 44)];
    tempImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user.png"];

    UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(44, 0, 80, 44)];
    tempLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tempLabel.text = title;
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tempLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    tempLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    tempLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8;
    [tempView addSubview:tempImageView];
    [tempView addSubview:tempLabel];
    UIBarButtonItem *userView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:tempView];
    NSArray *items = @[spacer ,userView];
    self.navigationTableViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = items;
}

- (void)navigateToHome {
    [self setRightNavigationBarViewForUser];
    self.loginViewController = nil;
    [self showCenterPanelAnimated:YES];
    [self setLeftBarButtonForDrawerTitle];
    NSAssert([self.centreViewController isKindOfClass:[GGBaseViewController class]], @"Must be of GGBaseViewController class");
    [GenreNavigator navigateToRoot:(GGBaseViewController*)self.centreViewController completionHandler:nil];
}
```

My code is given above: The problem, I am facing is that navigation right bar button items are not visible first time when I navigate to home. When I navigate to some other page and comes back then its visible. The first method is used to create right navigation bar button items.

Comment: Check if `self.navigationTableViewController.navigationItem` is nil.

Comment: @KudoCC Thanks man, but its not nil,if it was nil button should not appear on returning back from a view.

Comment: You'd better config the navigation bar in `self.centreViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` method or try to move this line `[self setRightNavigationBarViewForUser];` to the bottom of the method `navigateToHome` (make sure you add the items after the pop action, maybe it should go in completionHandler)

Answer (score 1):

From Apple doc on rightBarButtonItems, you can see that most likely your custom view is too wide and your button is not showing because it does not fit. Test making it narrower and see if it appears?

Discussion
This array can contain 0 or more bar button items to display on the right side of the navigation bar. Items are displayed right-to-left in the same order as they appear in the array. Thus, the first item in the array is the rightmost item and other items are added to the left of the previous item.

If there is not enough room to display all of the items in the array, those that would overlap the title view (if present) or the buttons on the left side of the bar are not displayed.

Comment: Reference at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006933-CH3-SW15

Comment: It is appearing when I navigate from home to any other place and come back the view is perfect as I want.But it is not appearing when very first time I navigate to home.

Comment: maybe because after you navigate back home you are changing the left button bar, and there is more room? As I said, try making items narrow temporarily to confirm it is a width issue.